# Does linked brushing in Bokeh works with line charts?

Tags: python, bokeh

Does anyone know if linked brushing works with line charts? In the code below, when I select an area on chart1, nothing happens. But if I were to change line_chart1.line to line_chart1.circle, then all of a sudden my charts are synchronized and a selection on one chart and is matched with data on other charts.

```
# define line chart
TOOLS = "xbox_select,lasso_select,help"

line_chart1 = figure(tools=TOOLS, plot_height=300, plot_width=600, x_axis_type='datetime')
line_chart2 = figure(tools=TOOLS, plot_height=300, plot_width=600, x_axis_type='datetime')
line_chart3 = figure(tools=TOOLS, plot_height=300, plot_width=600, x_axis_type='datetime')

line_chart1.line('date', 'score', source=cds)
line_chart2.line('date', 'average', source=cds)
line_chart3.line('date', 'median', source=cds)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of current releases (1.4), Bokeh does not support selection or highlighting on lines in general, linked or not.